# React Sortable Tree - Can I give outside button "Add node" by finding type with tree data?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to Add node to parent by Outside Add button by matching the selected type with a tree. But I didn't get tree-index / path outside my tree. So I have passes hardcoded parent key to add child node. But If any node deleted parent key will be changed. So my code does not work.

```
if (this.state.parentNodeValue === 'Position') {

  parentKey = 10;
  nodeClassName = 'fa-position div';

}

let NEW_NODE = {
  title: this.state.englishName,
  arabicTitle: this.state.arabicName,
  className: nodeClassName
};

let newTree = addNodeUnderParent({
  treeData: this.state.treeData,
  newNode: NEW_NODE,
  expandParent: true,
  parentKey: parentKey,
  getNodeKey: ({
    treeIndex
  }) => treeIndex
});
this.setState({
  treeData: newTree.treeData,
  modalOuterAddNode: !this.state.modalOuterAddNode,
}, () => {
  // console.log('treeData : ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.treeData));
});
```

Comment: Hi, I solved this by my own. On outside Add button, opened form with list of titles of existing tree. After that I got index on clicking of title. Then I have added child to this parent index.

Answer (score 0):

By this code will get array of title with their index. Then we can add child node to these parent indexes.

let titleArray = [];

```
    var buildTree = function (tree) {
        _.each(tree, function (item) {
            let titleObj = {};
            // titleObj.id = item.id;
            titleObj.title = item.title;
            titleArray.push(titleObj);
            if (item.children) buildTree(item.children);
        });
    }
    buildTree(tree);
```